# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в следующем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в следующем предложении:

**Четыре варианта ответа, правильный из которых - первый, - вот и весь тест.**

Comment: Пожалуйста, не нужно предлагать перестроить предложение.

Comment: Тест — задача определения правильного варианта. Какой смысл в вашей  фразе? Ирония?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Четыре варианта ответа, правильный из которых первый, ― вот и весь тест.**

Два тире и две паузы для этого предложения ― это слишком много, интонационно сложно выразить, да и графическое оформление некрасивое.

Поэтому одним тире в неполном предложении придется пожертвовать.